# Пользователь вводит данные, как преобразовать эти данные в массив? (Данные типа int)

Tags: python, массивы, while, int

Подскажите, как преобразовать данные типа int в массив.
Пользователь вводит данные далее с помощью цикла while нужно перебрать все элементы.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0
i=list(input())
sp=[]
while a<len(i): 
    sp.append(int(i[a]))
    a+=1
print(sp)
```

Или так, через `for`, но короче:

```
a=[]
for i in list(input()): a.append(int(i))
print(a)
```

**Пример:**

*Ввод:*

```
345
```

*Вывод:*

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: а если без пробела вводить, то все введённые цифры будут записаны как один элемент

Comment: задача заключается в том, что пользователь вводит всего одно число и нужно перебрать все его цифры

Comment: Изменил, смотрите, выбирайте)